# Create Bitmap from View in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, screenshot

I want to create a bitmap from a view in Android, which basically works fine using the following approach: http://www.aquajava.hu/2011/06/19/converting-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it/

However, I want to modify this approach. Basically, my application supports multiple display densities for all kinds of resolution. Instead of creating a bitmap from a view based on the device's display, I want that the bitmap created always relies on the HDPI version. So although the display is maybe smaller I want to create a bitmap with 480 * 800 pixels. If I just increase the size of the bitmap, the font sizes and images still stay small according to the density. I don't want to just scale the image because the resolution would be quite poor then.

So basically, I search for a way to create a bitmap from a view ignoring the density of the view.

Does anybody know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling [setDensity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setDensity%28int%29) on your Bitmap?

Comment: Basically, a good idea. However, I don't want to change the density of the bitmap. I want to change the density the view is drawn onto the bitmap. I am able to create screenshots that are always 480*800 but then the fonts and images are still rendered according to the DeviceMetrics.